# Can't set authorization and token in headers with axios in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, header, jwt, axios, authorization

I'm trying to set a JWT token authentication on a VueJS client and PHP API (using Zend and firebase).
I manage to log an user in with the creation of a JWT token stored in LocalStorage. Now I would like to send back this token to the API (so as to the API decode the JWT and return associated infos). I try to set the "Authorisation: Bearer + token" in the header from VueJS using axios but I always have a problem. 
Here is a code snippet :

```
function getInfos() {
  return axios({
    method: 'get',
    url: MYURL,
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('user')
    }
  })
    .catch(handleResponse)

}
```

First I got this error :

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'MYURL' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.`

Then I don't have any Authorization in header when I want it in my PHP API :

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *');

$request = new Request();
```

I know that I probably have to use 
`axios.defaults.headers.post` or maybe `axios.interceptors` but I'm a beginner so I have no idea how to use it properly..

I hope someone will be able to help me ! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think * doesn't work when setting custom headers you have to Type in header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization') atleast that's an issue i had